# Can't return false when row not removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hello I am trying to delete a row but when there is a relation it doesnt delete it but still returns true

```
 public ActionResult Delete(int? User)
    {
        if (!User.HasValue)
            return Json(new { IsComplete = false });

        try
        {

            var item = Db.Institutions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == User.Value);
            Db.Institutions.Remove(item);
            Db.SaveChanges();


        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(new { IsComplete = false });
        }

        return Json(new { IsComplete = true });
    }
```

this is Delete as you see and here is script ;

```
  $(document).on("click", ".m-portlet__nav-link", function () {
        var myDataText = $(this).data('title');
        var myDataId = $(this).data('id');
        var myDataUrl = $(this).data('url') + "/" + myDataId;
        $(".modal-body .dataIdFromJs").text(myDataText);

        $("#saveChanges").click(function () {

            var User = myDataId;

            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Institution")',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'User': User }),
                success: function (data) {

                    toastr.options = {
                        "closeButton": true,
                        "debug": false,
                        "newestOnTop": false,
                        "progressBar": false,
                        "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
                        "preventDuplicates": true,
                        "onclick": null,
                        "showDuration": "300",
                        "hideDuration": "1000",
                        "timeOut": "5000",
                        "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                        "showEasing": "swing",
                        "hideEasing": "linear",
                        "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                        "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
                    };

                    toastr.success("İşleminiz başarıyla tamamdlandı.");


                },
                error: function (data) {

                    toastr.options = {
                        "closeButton": true,
                        "debug": false,
                        "newestOnTop": false,
                        "progressBar": false,
                        "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
                        "preventDuplicates": true,
                        "onclick": null,
                        "showDuration": "300",
                        "hideDuration": "1000",
                        "timeOut": "5000",
                        "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                        "showEasing": "swing",
                        "hideEasing": "linear",
                        "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                        "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
                    };

                    toastr.error("Hata, tekrar deneyiniz!");


                }
            });

        });
    });
```

when there is no relation it is working and returning true also deleting the row but when there is relation it doesnt delete the row but still returns true how can I return false when row is not deleted due to relations

Comment: Returning `false` does not mean you execute the `error: function (data) {` code - its a perfectly valid response. You need to test the response - `success: function (data) { if(data.IsComplete) { you returned true } else { you returned false };` Alternatively do not catch the exception so the `error: function()` is executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `error: function (data)` in your AJAX call never gets called until something unexpected (i.e. 404 error) happened at server.

According to lines of code you've written will always fall in  `success: function (data)` because you are handling exception and returning some response.

As @Stephen Muecke  advised in his comment you should either not use catch so that it calls `error` function of AJAX or just check

```
success: function (data) 
{ 
  if(data.IsComplete) 
   { 
    // success toast
   } 
  else 
   {
    //error toast
   };
}
```